# How to dynamically allocate an array in a function?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to dynamically allocate an array passed through a parameter in the function `dynamic_allocation_array` and I don't understand why isn't it working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void dynamic_allocation_array(int **a, int n){

    (*a) = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", *(a + i));
    }

}
int main()
{
    int n, *a;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    dynamic_allocation_array(&a, n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you over complicate the simple thing. Functions have return values to handle it. Double pointers are needed if you return something and need to return the pointer as well.

Comment: using your login malloc prototype should look like this `void malloc(void **, size_t);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*(a + i)` is invalid. You want first to `*` dereference the `a` pointer , then add `+ i`. The `a` points to some variable, there is no at `a + i`. You allocated memory at `(*a) + i`.

Also you want to allocate the memory for `n` count of `int`s, not for `n` pointers to `int`. You want: `malloc(n * sizeof(int))`.

Use temp variable, don't use `*(a + b)` just use `a[b]` notation, make it clearer:

```
void dynamic_allocation_array(int **a, int n) {
    int *tmp = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &tmp[i]);
    }

    *a = tmp;
}
```

or you can:

```
void dynamic_allocation_array(int **a, int n) {
    *a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &(*a)[i]);
    }
}
```

or you can:

```
void dynamic_allocation_array(int **a, int n) {
    *a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", *a + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `malloc(n * sizeof(int))` ? Since memory is needed for `n` values, not `n` pointers.

Comment: ... or instead of `(int*)` even better, as safer: `sizeof *tmp` or `sizeof **a`.

Comment: Best would be `n * sizeof **a`.

Comment: best will ne removing the double pointer and return the allocated space reference instead

Comment: the idea with the temporary variable is a life-saving tip. Now I don't need to worry about this many pointers when the teacher requires us to use a function :)

Answer (score 2):

I would not use any double pointers as it is 100% not needed here

```
int *dynamic_allocation_array(size_t size)
{
      int *a = malloc(size * sizeof(*a));
       /* another code */
      return a;
}
```

and in the calling function

`int *a = dynamic_allocation_array(some_size);`